# Wordpress Flipbook Loading Time

Tags: wordpress, loading

I'm using the wordpress plugin **Dflip flipbook**, on this [page](http://mti-eng.gam3ity.com/courses/comm-l/lessons/animate/), and it takes about 2 minutes to load the pdf file which is about 5MB, any advices on how to make it load faster than this?

Comment: Make the pdf smaller. And that's not being snarky. A large file is going to range in loading time depending on the users internet connection, and a 5mb pdf is never going to be instant. How long is it taking (more specific than 'too long')?

Comment: about 2 minutes

Comment: How can i make the pdf smaller?, like compressing-wise?

Comment: Only took a few seconds to load for me, but yeah, making the PDF smaller is your best bet to improve loading time.

Comment: Is it taking that long to load the actual file or to render the plugin functionality? It may be an issue with the actual plugin. Because it definitely should not take 2 minutes to load a 5mb pdf. The plugin may be doing some kind of rendering from pdf to html or an image or something. Can you prerender an image from the pdf and serve that to the flipbook plugin instead?

Comment: Yea, to agree with @APAD1, it only took it about 10 seconds to load for me on that page.

Comment: Well, if i used images instead of pdf, that would make it even harder, i used a 500KB pdf, and it has like 2 sec loading time, so it doesn't have anything with the plugin functionality i guess.

Comment: Well, i live in Egypt, thus i have a 100KB per second connection, so do all the people visiting my website, so i need to make it load even faster than this.

Comment: Any advices on how to make the PDF smaller in wordpress?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#optimize

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is based on PDF.js so supports partial loading of pdf.. like in their demo.. The plugin should start with just less than 1MB of PDF data..

So if you can disable gzipping of PDFs through server setting.. the partial loads should work by default..